# JsHint integration with MSBuild or TFS 2010 Team Build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, jshint

I am looking Jshint integration with MSBuild or TFS 2010 Team Build.

JShint show error while running with CI or Gated Checked in build on that case build should failed.

i have tried with sharplinter but its show error on output window but its not build failed. build was succeed .